# Is there a guide to cross-compiling ROS for ARM (BBB)?

Tags: ros, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The eROS project appears to be graveyarded and I'm looking for a place to start.

My Requirements:

- Build ROS Packages in amd64 machine with cross compiler
- "Deploy" binaries on target - Beaglebone black - which already has ROS installed on it
- Run ROS nodes on the target

I *can* build the ROS packages on the BBB itself but that workflow gets out of hand for distributed systems - a cluster of 10-20 BBBs that may all run an instance of the built ROS package..

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203973/is-there-a-guide-to-cross-compiling-ros-for-arm-(bbb)?/) by [Pranav](https://answers.ros.org/users/21526/pranav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you consider [meta-ros](https://github.com/bmwcarit/meta-ros/) or [beagle-ros](http://vmayoral.github.io/beagle-ros/)? Additional relevant links are:

- http://wiki.ros.org/BeagleBone
- http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OpenEmbedded

---

Originally posted by [slivingston](https://answers.ros.org/users/829/slivingston/) with karma: 254 on 2015-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pranav](https://answers.ros.org/users/21526/pranav/) on 2015-02-28**:
Hey thanks for pointing me in this direction! I've got it working now thanks to the pages you've given me. beagle-ros environment setup + meta-ros enabled me to bitbake user-defined recipes for ROS packages that I was able to deploy and successfully run on BBB. Thanks!